# foreach loop is disappeared after coming back to page in blazor server app

Tags: blazor

When I go to a new page and return back the the foreach loop in my component is not back on the screen until I do a page refresh. The rest of the code in the component does stay on the page. don't know how to fix this.

Before

[image: 1]

After

[image: 2]

this is happening in the "SideBaRight" components.

```
<header>

<SidebarLeft/>
<SidebarRight @ref="sideBar" loggedInUser="@loggedInUser"/>

<div class="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <TopBar/>
            <InfoBanner/>
            <UserSquares/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the component

```
<nav id="sidebarMenu2" class="collapse d-lg-block sidebar-right bg-white">
    <div class="position-sticky">
        <div class="list-group mx-3">
            <div class="list-group-item border-0 ripple" aria-current="true">
                <img class="position-relative top-0 start-50 translate-middle-x" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/28/3a/b1/283ab1108ef8e379a2e555de019e1aee.jpg" alt="Lamp" width="150" height="150">
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item border-0 py-2 ripple" aria-current="true">
                <span class="fw-bold">Name</span>
                <br />
                <span>@loggedInUser.FirstName @loggedInUser.LastName</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item border-0 py-2 ripple" aria-current="true">
                <span class="fw-bold">Height</span>
                <span>@loggedInUser.Height</span>
            </div>
            <div class="list-group-item border-0 py-2 ripple" aria-current="true">
                <span class="fw-bold">Age</span>
                <span>@CalculateAge(loggedInUser.DateOfBirth)</span>
            </div>

            @foreach (var m in loggedInUser.Subscriptions)
            {
                if (m.IsActive == true)
                {
                    <div class="list-group-item border-0 py-2 ripple" aria-current="true">
                        <span class="fw-bold">Coached by </span>
                        <br />
                        <span>@FindCoach(m.Coach)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group-item border-0 py-2 ripple" aria-current="true">
                        <span class="fw-bold">Start Coaching</span>
                        <br />
                        <span>@m.SubscriptionStartDate</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group-item border-0 py-2 ripple" aria-current="true">
                        <span class="fw-bold">Next Billing</span>
                        <br />
                        <span>@NextBilling(m.SubscriptionLenght, m.SubscriptionTypeMonth)</span>
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you have any console errors when the subscriptions are missing? Are you certain the loggedInUser is not null when you do a page refresh?

Comment: We can't see how you "return back" or how you manage the Parameters.

Comment: No errors relating the issue. De loggedInUser is presented on the screen. I Realize now that object i'm using is linked with a foreign key with entity framework. I'm not storing that object.